# Add a date column in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, csv, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am wondering if it is possible to add a date column to each file uploaded.

For example each month a CSV is produced. I am wanted to add for example "December 2020" to each row and then for the next months upload add "January 2021" to every row in the CSV file. Before copying this into a SQL database.

e.g. file name "Latest Rating December 2020" I would want the 'December 2020' as a column and be the same value for all rows. The naming convention will be the same for each months upload.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can use Get MetaData activity to get the file name and intercept string as column content,  then use **additional column** of Copy Activity in ADF to add this column content for each row when you copy them into sql table.

Comment: Do it in a Data Flow activity. Use a Derived Column activity and use currentDate() as the function or parse the file name to get the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a test to add a column to the csv file.
The result is as follows:
[image]

1. We can get file name via `Child Items` in Get MetaData activity.
   [image]
   The dataset is to the container in ADLS.
   [image]
2. Then we can declare a variable `FileName` to store the file name via the expression  `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0].name`.
   [image]

3.We can use **additional column** in Copy activity, and use the expression `@concat(split(variables('FileName'),' ')[2],' ',split(variables('FileName'),' ')[3])` to
get the value we need. **Note** that the single quote contains a space.
[image]
In the dataset, we need key in a dynamic content `@variables('FileName')` to specify which file to be copied.
[image]
The sink is the same as source in Copy activity.
[image]

4. Then we can run debug to confirm it.

Here I think we also can copy into SQL table directly, when we set the sink to a sql table.

Comment: Thanks for this. So for example each month I have a file that I want to upload the same naming convention e.g. 'Latest Rating December 2020'. So would i have to create a pipeline and repeat this process each time? Or is there a way to automate this so I would only have to upload the file each month and it would run through the same pipeline?

Comment: There is a way to automate do this. In ADF we can use triggers to trigger the pipeline run. If I remember correctly, there is an event type trigger, when a new csv file was uploaded to the Azure then will trigger the pipeline running.

Comment: Xu This works for me however sometimes the column headers are different and this breaks the pipeline? do I have to manually change the column headers to match in the CSV? or can you do this in Azure?

Comment: I don't quite understand about your problem, could you please add more details or ask another question?

Comment: So for example each file will be uploaded monthly but some months the column header might change name from the previous months file. e.g:

ID - Location ID - Domain

ID - Location ID - Key Question

The 'Domain' and 'Key Question' are the same but the names changed. and when running this file in Azure it comes up with an error 'no column for key question' I am wanting to map this the same as the domain

Comment: Maybe we can change to use dataflow after Get MetaData activity(pass the file name as a parameter to the dataflow), in the source we can allow schema drift.